# Drag and Drop (Swap, Remove) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create an application to practice and understand drag and drop.

My application has a drop zone, a toolbar for the draggable items and a drop zone to delete the items.

What is not being able to do is swapping position between two item in the drop zone. When I try to change position by dragging one over the other, another drop is performed over the previous element.

Here is the [code pen link](http://codepen.io/miller619/pen/WoVpdE) to my application.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Drop Zone</legend>
  <div id="dz" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div class="card text-xs-center">
  <div class="card-block">
    <div id="textbox">
      <div id="dti1" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label for="ti1">Text Input</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ti1" placeholder="text">
      </div>
      <div id="dti2" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label for="ti2">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ti2" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div id="dti3" class="form-group" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <label for="ti3">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="ti3" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="delete" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="del(event)">Drop here to delete </div>
</div>
```

this image will give you an idea of what I'm saying

[image: this image will give you an idea of what I'm saying]

Comment: Don't allow the drop function to be repeated in the drop zone itself because this is allowing duplication of form element entries, which is the cause of your issue.

Comment: I did not really understand your solution. If I do not allow the drop function in the drop zone then it does not work at all.

Comment: Allow the drop function, but not on items already in that zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the drop inside the other element, you can add a check of the `id`:

```
function allowDrop(e) {
    'use strict';
    if (e.target.id === 'dz') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This will allow drop only to the main container

Comment: you're welcome, implementing the swap is not that easy, try yourself and link questions here if you have them. Take a look at [this library](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/simple.) Also, consider accepting the answer if it answered your question